# assign database value for variable in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, variables

This is about Android and SQLite database.

Simply, I want to know, how can I assign value to variable that get from the Database table?

I have table called **wish** and colmns are date[date value string], phoneno[phone no string] and wishtype[simply a string].

All I want is get phoneno, and wishtype according to usergiven date[input to the query will be the date] and assign those two into seperate variable.

I tried out so many methods, but it gives me a runtime errors.

Comment: Please put some code for us to know what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: What methods did you try? What errors did you receive? Did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String phone_no;
String wish_type;
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(your_table_uri, 
  new String[] {"_id", "phone_no", "wish_type", "date" /*these are your column names*/},
  "date=?", your_date_filter, null);
if(c.moveToFirst()) { // checks if c retrieves anything. you may want to check first if   c!=null
      phone_no = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phone_no"));
      wish_type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("wish_type"));
    }
```

Comment: im Doing this on class extends by BroatcastReciever... The problem is getContentResolver() is not in intelligence list.... am i want to import any package to enable this...??

Comment: BroadcastReceiver's onReceive has a context parameter. use that to get the content resolver.

Comment: K... thank you for help josephus... last thing i want to know what is the meaning of Table Uri.... is it the table name...or path...???

Comment: it's the table path including the table name